# React clone stateful component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

When cloning a stateful component using [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement), is the state kept?

Comment: No, state is not preserved.

Answer (score 2):

`cloneElement` clones React *element,* not an instance of underlying *component*.

This results in [creating new element](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v16.6.3/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L356) that has same type, key, ref as original element and also inherits props from it.

React element is an object that is created by `createElement`. It's basically a blueprint that is used to render a component. It may have no respective component instances at all, in case it wasn't rendered.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to keep clone an element while keeping its state?

Comment: You're confusing elements and components. An element doesn't have a state. It's a template that is used by React renderer to create component instance. You can check what it looks like. `<Foo bar={1}/>` is an object like `{ type: Foo, props: { bar: 1 } }`. When passed to a renderer, it basically tells to create an instance of Foo class and assign { bar: 1 } object as props property. What's your case? The question is possibly XY problem.